# How to use CSS3 transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="welcome-content">
 // Code
</div>
<div id="configure-content" style="display:none">
 // Code
</div>
```

And (working) jquery that toggles between them:

```
$('.back-welcome').click(function(){
$('#welcome-content').toggle();
$('#configure-content').toggle();        
});
```

I want to use CSS3 to create a fade effect as I toggle between them. I have tried the following:

```
#welcome-content, #configure-content{
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
    -o-transition: all 400ms;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms;
    -ms-transition: all 400ms;
    -khtml-transition: all 400ms;
}
```

However, no animation takes place. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for fading in and out you could transition between `opacity:0` and `opacity:1` in the css to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property `display` that assign the method `toggle ()` can't be animated with the CSS transitions. Maybe you want to look at `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

**Edit**

I've found this another method [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) i don't know much about it but you can search and use this:

```
$('.back-fade').click(function(){
  $('#welcome-content').fadeToggle(2000);
  $('#configure-content').fadeToggle(2000);        
});
```

Check this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/8urRp/14/** *

---

*<sub>I made the divs with absolute position to keep them on the same space</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There can only be a transition for a CSS property from one value to another. For a fade transition, the `opacity` should go from 0 to one.

CSS

```
.foo {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 400ms;
}
.foo.active {
   opacity: 1
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.mybtn').click(function() { $('.foo').toggleClass('active'); })
```

**[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/RZGNV/)**

---

Now there is an annoying thing with showing an hiding elements using with CSS transitions. The transition from `display: none` to `display: block` is instant, canceling out all other transitions.

There are several ways around this. First you can just use the jQuery `fadeOut` function. If you do really insist in using CSS transitions have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-propertyh#3332179).